# Show that there is a continuous function such that $f(x) = \frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^x t^2\sin(f(t))dt$ for every $x \in [0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Notation: $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ is the normed vector space of the continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to the real line, with norm $|f| = \sup \{|f(x)|, x \in [0,1]\}$

Show that there is a continuous funtcion $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x \in [0,1]$ it satisfies:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{x}t^2\sin(f(t))\,dt$$

Well, I am trying to solve this exercise. My idea is to show that the functional $J:C([0,1],\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ given by $J(f(x)) = \dfrac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{x}t^2\sin(f(t))\,dt$ has a fixed point. I am trying to show that this functional is a contraction and then conclude that there is a function $f$ such that $J(f) = f$, but I am struggling to find upper bounds for |J(f) - J(g)|. Any hints to find upper bounds for this functional?

Comment: Use that $|\sin(x)|\le|x|$.

Comment: Martin's answer is the way to go . . . but if you explicitly want to find upper bounds for $|J(f) - J(g)|$, then $$
|J(f)- J(g)| = \left\vert \int_0^x t^2(\sin(f(t)) - \sin(g(t))) \; dt \right\vert \le \int_0^x t^2 | \sin f(t) - \sin g(t)| \; dt
$$ and now apply Mean Value Theorem for $\sin f(t) - \sin g(t)$

Comment: The function $f(x)\equiv0$ is the only solution to this problem.

Comment: @user288742 Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: Will do @ArcticChar

Answer (score 4):

Observe that
$$|J(f(x))- J(g(x))| = \left\vert \int_0^x t^2(\sin(f(t)) - \sin(g(t))) \; dt \right\vert \le \int_0^x t^2 | \sin f(t) - \sin g(t)| \; dt
$$
and by the Mean  Value Theorem,
$$\begin{split}
& \sin f(t) - \sin g(t) = \cos(\xi_t) (f(t) - g(t)) \\
\implies &|\sin f(t) - \sin g(t)| \le |f(t) - g(t)| \le \|f-g\|_\infty
\end{split}$$
so that
$$|J(f(x))- J(g(x))| \le \|f - g\|_\infty \int_0^x t^2 dt \le \|f-g\|_\infty  \int_0^1 t^2 \; dt = \frac{\|f-g\|_\infty}{3}.
$$

Taking the supremum over all $x \in [0,1]$ on the LHS, we have
$$
\|J f - Jg\|_\infty \le  \frac{\|f-g\|_\infty}{3}
$$
and by Contraction Mapping Theorem $J(f(x))$ has a unique fixed point.

Comment: It seems that $f(x)=2\arctan e^{x^3/9}$ : assume that $f'$ exists, then $\frac{f'(x)}{\sin f(x)} = \frac{x^2}{3}$, integrating both sides we get $f(x)=2\arctan e^{x^3/9}$.